# Gradle - Suppress gradle to create application.xml

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I am trying to build an ear using gradle.

I would like to use the META-INF/application.xml that is already present in the project. And do not have the gradle generate one for me.

i tried the following code snippet and the archive(EAR) has TWO application.xml files in META-INF instead of just the copied one.

```
ear {
     into("META-INF") {
        from("META-INF")
     }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your existing `application.xml` under the `META-INF` in the source folder. If Gradle already find the file then it won't generate one. You can read more about the behavior in the [Gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ear_plugin.html#sec:using_custom_app_xml).

Comment: Thanks. Per documentation gradles looks for META_INF in src/main/application folder. But the EAR project that I have in eclipse does not have src/main/application. META_INF folder is at root level.